# Merged Excel Column Headers in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to read an excel file that has some merged column headers using pandas. The file looks as below:

[image]

I want the output to be as below:

[image]

After loading it to pandas, the output comes as below:

[image]

Does anyone know how I can handle this in Pandas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is usually called multiple headers, - and `pd.read_excel` also `pd.read_csv` has options to represent it.
simply use, `header` parameter.
Later flatten the header as per example below:

```
df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', header=[0,1]) # using first and second row as headers (pandas count rows from 0).
df.columns = ['.'.join(col).strip() for col in df.columns.values] # flattening headers to a single row, - joining them using ".".
```

you can also test/play with `to_flat_index()` function, but I have not found it attractive.

```
df.columns = df.columns.to_flat_index()
```

Comment: Thanks. Both suggestions worked for my scenario